# I'm having trouble using the useSWR hook in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, swr

I'm working on a project that uses the useSWR hook inside my pages in Nextjs. I make the request to the rest api provided by Nextjs (/api/..). However my data is always undefined although the api receives the request (there is no error too - its value is undefined). I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then(res => res.json());
const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/hello', fetcher)
```

This is what '/api/hello' looks like:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  name: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  console.log('server hit')
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'John Doe' })
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Do you see the console.log?

Comment: Yes, my terminal prints undefined but the browser console prints the correct object. I am confused as to why this occurs. I can also access the object in the html I am returning. However when I try to deconstruct the object, it throws an error.

Comment: When the page is SSR'd and on initial render on the client `data` will be undefined as `useSWR` will only call the fetcher method and fetch the data when the component gets mounted. You need to handle that accordingly in your component's code.